# How to Defining javascript function within PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to run this on scroll java script function in the P H P code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('scroll', function()
```

Here Is the PHP code and I need to  Defining javascript function in the else

```
if(!empty($text_block_05_title)):{

} else:{
    ...In HERE IN NEED TO RUN THE FUNCTION..
}
```

Comment: Inside your PHP code write `echo "$(window).on('scroll', function(){..."`

Comment: Php runs on server while javascript runs in browser. you need to do an ajax request to run that php function.

Answer (score 1):

you can not run php code within jquery. instead it, go for ajax like this

> $.ajax({ url: 'test.php', success: function(data) { alert(data); } });

in test.php file write your if statements

> if (!empty($text_block_05_title)) {
>
> } else {  ...In HERE IN NEED TO RUN THE FUNCTION.. }

Comment: It's Wordpress Site and I can't add 
$.ajax({ url: 'test.php', success: function(data) { alert(data); } });
This code in thare